# How to concatenate/merge strings of this pattern in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Suppose I have the following Parameters.

```
ENABLE='Y'
CHECK1="MAILBOX"
ID="abc@gmail.com, bcd@gmail.com"
```

If ENABLE='Y'. then i want

MAILBOX="abc@gmail.com, bcd@gmail.com"

Is there a way to acheive this?

Comment: is this present on a text file?

Comment: Yes. Avinash This is on a text file

Comment: What's your expected output if enable to y?

Comment: I want a string printed as `MAILBOX="abc@gmail.com, bcd@gmail.com"`

Comment: is that the mailbox string comes from the second line?

Comment: Yes Basically i'm trying to fetch the value in variable `CHECK1` and `ID` and then merging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F"=|'|\"" 'NR==1&&$3=="Y"{yes=1} /CHECK/{chk=$3} /ID=/&&yes{printf ("%s=\"%s\"\n",chk,$3)}' File
```

Else, you can put this script in a file `myfile.awk`

```
BEGIN {
  FS="=|'|\""
}

NR==1&&$3=="Y"{yes=1}
/CHECK/{chk=$3}
/ID=/&&yes{printf("%s=\"%s\"\n", chk, $3)}
```

and execute like `awk -f myfile.awk File`.

We set the delimiters as `=`, `'` and `"`. In the first line `(NR==1)`,  check if ENABLE='`Y`', then set variable `yes=1`. Then, when `CHECK` is matched, it will save the check string after `=` to variable `chk`. Then, when `ID=` is matched (i.e in the last line), it will print `chk string="addresses"` if `yes = 1`.

Comment: Could shorten a bit, `awk -F"=|'|\"" 'NR==1&&$3=="Y"{yes=1} /CHECK/{chk=$3} /ID=/&&yes{print chk"="$3)}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "/ENABLE/,/ID/ {
   H
   /ID/ {
      s/.*//
      x
      /ENABLE='Y'/ s/.*CHECK1=\"\([^\"]*\).*ID=/\1/p
      }
   }" YourFile
```

- assume file is filled with correct sequence and full content (only X * the 3 lines)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you(GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^ENABLE='\''Y'\''$/{n;N;s/.*"(.*)".*(".*").*/\1=\2/p}' file
```

If a line contains `ENABLE='Y'` then discard it and read in the next two lines and pattern match on double quotes. If the match is successful print the desired result otherwise print nothing.